# How to create an instance of KnownHostsServerKeyVerifier for host key verification in the SSHClient of Apache Mina SSHD java library

Tags: java, ssh, apache-sshd, known-hosts

I am trying to connect to a remote server using the SshClient of java library `Apache MINA SSHD`.

I want to pass my `known_hosts` file also to the `SshClient` so that the hosts are also verified before connecting to the server.
I need to use the class `KnownHostsServerKeyVerifier` to pass the known hosts the the client like below

```
ServerKeyVerifier hostsServerKeyVerifier = new KnownHostsServerKeyVerifier(null, Paths.get("<path_to_known_hosts>/known_hosts"));
client.setServerKeyVerifier(hostsServerKeyVerifier);
```

The contructor of `KnownHostsServerKeyVerifier` need below arguments

```
public KnownHostsServerKeyVerifier(ServerKeyVerifier delegate, Path file)
```

But I don't understand what and how to pass for the argument **ServerKeyVerifier**

Can someone explain me how to make this work or is there some other approach to pass the `known_hosts` file to the `SshClient` ?